# MongoDB group by UNIX time and count not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a document which looks like,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dffd3b65291f06dab34385"),
    "user" : "12345667890"
    "time" : NumberLong(1474297140186)
}
```

I am trying to count number of visitors for a certain application. I have 64 fields and my query looks as below.

```
db.convo_log.aggregate([
   {
       '$group': {
            '_id': { 
                month: { $month: new Date("$time") }, 
                day: { $dayOfMonth: new Date("$time") }, 
                year: { $year: new Date("$time") } 
            }, 
            'count': { '$sum': 1 }
       }
   }
])
```

Even though I am looking for a several groups (as there is data from different days) it returns as,

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 8,
        "day" : 17,
        "year" : 292278994
    },
    "count" : 64.0
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I failed to see the `entry` field in your document. What is the expected result with the document you've  shown us? Also note that you can't create new date using existing field value that way.

Comment: @Styvane pardon me. I corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a date object representation from a timestamp that way. You would need to do some arithmetic manipulation using the [arithmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) i.e. **[`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#exp._S_add)** the timestamp to a `new Date(0)` object constructor which represents the date as 0 millisecond from epoch (though in a shorter form).

The sum `{ "$add": ["$time", new Date(0)] }` results in a new date object. So putting this altogether with the **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString)** operator, you can run this pipeline to get the desired result:

```
db.convo_log.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "formattedDate": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                    "date": { "$add": ["$time", new Date(0)] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$formattedDate",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```